# Retrieve HTTP request packet data in Apache or Flask

Tags: apache, flask, httprequest

I've completed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

So now I have a "hello world" flask app.

Pointing my browser to mysite.org/flask gives a "hello world" page.

As an instructive exercise, I would like to instead have it display the entire contents of the HTTP request that Apache just received.

How to go about doing this?  How can I view the contents of this request from the Apache level?  And how do I access this data from Flask?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to get the entire raw request data.

I think it is impossible to get it straight up. Because the request might have an arbitrary length body, which would have to be retrieved in stages maybe.

The following code prints out the header and the client's IP.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from flask import request

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return '<p>' + 'Got request!' + '</p>' + \
        '<p>' + str( request.headers ) + '</p>' + \
        '<p>' + request.remote_addr + '</p>'
```